# sending null keyboardInfo as SIP is closed

Tags: android

So my Android application keeps stopping when I try to start an intent and move to a new activity. This is the error I'm getting.

E/KeyboardInfoUtils: sending null keyboardInfo as SIP is closed

I've never seen this exception before, and can't find any help online. Can anyone help me please.